# Migration to SilverStripe 3.0 and Zend_Translate

Tags: internationalization, silverstripe, zend-translate

I am migrating a website from SS 2.4 to SS 3.0 and I am having an immensely difficult time due to the fact that the SilverStripe documentation is full of dead links (about every link I have clicked on the [3.0.0 documentation page](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.0/) is dead) and holes such as incomplete sentences or pages that show up among search results but cannot be reached.

Specifically, the website I am working on runs in two locales (en_US and fr_FR) and I used (in SS 2.4) to use `i18n::include_locale_file`. Now, after finding the appropriate modules and upgrading the custom code, I get a deprecation notice that I don't know how to solve and to which web searches bring no answer:

```
[User Deprecated] i18n::include_locale_file is deprecated. Use Zend_Translate instead.
```

The problem is that there's [zero example](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4.0/changelogs/3.0.0/#zend-translate) of what is to be done. There's no upgrade path available to be followed. I just don't get how I can replace old code such as this:

```
i18n::include_locale_file('framework', 'fr_FR');
global $lang;

if(array_key_exists('fr_FR', $lang) && is_array($lang['fr_FR'])) {
    $lang['fr_FR'] = array_merge($lang['fr_FR'], $lang['fr_FR']);
} else {
    $lang['fr_FR'] = $lang['fr_FR'];
}
```

This was standard code in SS 2.4 and can be found for instance in language files of sapphire and cms.

As I understand it, Zend_Translate is part of a framework. Is there a possibility to express simply the inclusion of another translation file? Or the layering of two translation files?

I thought of using the yml converter so I can be in line with the recommendations but it works as CLI on a Unix system and I'm working on a Windows system. With all the time I have spent on this migration, and the frustration with the documentation, I now regret having picked SS but I can only go forward. Therefore, I'm looking for a simple solution, not one that would require installing a virtual machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have php files as lang files? e.g. *mysite/lang/fr_FR.php* ? You'll have to move this to yml files or use Zend_Translate instead ;)

See https://github.com/jakr/miscellaneous-wiki/wiki/SilverStripe-3-Quick-Upgrade-Guide#translation-file-format-changed-from-php-to-yml and https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.0/changelogs/3.0.0#zend-translate

From the latter, define in your */mysite/config.php*:

```
i18n::register_translator(
    new Zend_Translate(array(
        'adapter' => 'i18nSSLegacyAdapter',
        'locale' => i18n::default_locale(),
        'disableNotices' => true,
    )),
    'legacy',
    9 // priority lower than standard translator
);
```

to get the old php files working again. Depending on how many language strings you have i'd move it to .yml.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but as I've said in the question, I have visited these links. None of them solves the problem of either moving to yml without rebuilding the yml file by hand or writing a custom converter from scratch, and the problem of the old include_locale_file for layering translation files. For now, I have worked around it by commenting out the block of code I have quoted.

Comment: Well, the code snippet above should make your old php language files working again. Did you try it?